# What's the Power BI rendering engine?

Tags: powerbi

What's the rendering software piece that Power BI uses to draw the visuals?

It's has been developed or bought by Microsoft?

I had read that visuals are built with JavaScript, could it be an browser rendering engine like Chromium's Blink and libraries like D3.js?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be mostly JavaScript/TypeScript.

You can check out this [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Visuals) for documentation regarding creating Power BI visuals or search all of the [repositories related to Power BI visuals](https://github.com/Microsoft?&q=PowerBI-visuals).

They do explicitly mention d3 in their [Adding External Libraries](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/ExternalLibraries.md#including-javascript-files) section.